# Gatsby hydration error on production but everything works fine locally

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I am working on a Gatsby site and using server side code. Everything seems to work locally but in production (Netlify) we have errors logged to the console.
The errors are:

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message

The errors are related to UI mismatch but I am unable to reproduce them locally.